# What property is used to extend negative modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My professor has this one line in his homework that has me completely tripping:

"Note that if x (mod y)= z (mod y), then x−z = ky for some integer k. We can use this property to extend mod to negative numbers as well, i.e., −4 (mod 6) = 2, −1024912489 (mod 10) = 1. "

What does he mean by "extend"? I don't see how this property extends anything, and I don't understand what it has to do with negative mod.

Help?

Comment: Well, do you understand why $-4\pmod6\equiv2$? It is because $2 - (-4)$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Does your professor really write things like $x\pmod y=z\pmod y$ instead of $x\equiv z \pmod y$?

Comment: it seems your professor has first defined the modulo arithmetic over non-negative integers and then use the stated property to extend the "definition" over all integers.

Comment: Your professor's point seems to be that negative numbers can be equivalent to something modulo something else. Are you having trouble digesting that fact, or is this really a question about the word “extend”?

Comment: Please state  the definition of "mod" that your professor gave.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is referring to the fact that if $$x-z=ky$$ then you can say $$x\equiv z \ \mod y $$
without worrying whether $x$ or $z$ are negative.

Comment: or equivalently that x and z are both on ky+z